# Static field lifespan in Android

Tags: java, android, static, garbage-collection

Quick question, but one I can't find an answer to in the documentation.

**What is the lifespan of a static field in an Android App?**  When is it initialized and when is it destroyed? Does the final attribute modify its lifecycle? What about private/public? Do they live as long as the Application instance is alive?

Take two instances:

```
public class DemoClass {
   static int one = 1;
   static int three = DemoActivity.two + one;
}

public class DemoActivity extends Activity {
     public static int two = DemoClass.one + DemoClass.one;
     private static final int four;
     public static int five;

     public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
          four = two + two;
          five = DemoClass.three  + DemoClass.one + DemoClass.one;

     }

}
```

Edit: Also what about static dictionaries?

For instance,

```
public class AnotherDemoActivity extends Activity {
public static ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
   strings.add("test");
   strings.add(new String("another test");
   strings.add(new DemoClass());
}
```

How long will the "strings" elements live for?

Answer (score 5):

> When is it initialized and when is it destroyed?

It is initialized when the class that declares it is loaded, It will survive until your application process ends.

> Does the final attribute modify its lifecycle?

No

> What about private/public?

No

> Do they live as long as the Application instance is alive?

Yes

Comment: Does the Application class load all its classes? When would DemoClass get loaded? Assume it's a public class declared in its own file if that matters.

Comment: I believe its the same as the Java class loader and will only load classes when they are referenced by other classes being loaded, DemoClass would be loaded when a referencing class is loaded such as your DemoActivity

Comment: I believe that too, I just can't seem to find any documentation to support it! :)

Comment: I am not sure if you would really need to care in respect to static variables because they are effectively useless unless you actually use them, so at the point you use them you can be sure that they have been initialized

Answer (score 1):

- `static` scope is till the class is un-deployed.     It will be
  initiated on initiation (right after load ).
  No. final attribute doesn't modify above behavior.

Comment: "static scope is till the class is un-deployed." What does that mean? What if I never instantiate that class?

Comment: You don't need to instantiate a class to access static variables, they are not instance scoped, they are class scoped.